# How to ensure three images per row in a mapped table?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, html-table

I have a list of img urls[img1,img2,img3,img4,img5]

i mapped all the images into tables like this.

However, the images will be rendered like this

`img1 img2 img3 img4 img5`

How do i make it so theres only 3 imgs per row?:

```
img1 img2 img3

  img4  img5
```

```
return (
    <table className = "table">
      <tbody>
        {this.state.imgs2.map(imageUrl => {
            return (
                <td>{this.renderImage(imageUrl, "150", "150")}</td>
            );
        })
        }
      </tbody>
    </table>
    )
```

Comment: it is a css question, what you can do is that you can display your `tbody ` as `display:flex` and `flex-wrap: wrap` and add specific width to your  `td `s

Answer (score 0):

wrap each 3 imgs inside `<tr>`

```js
import _ from lodash;
....
return (
    <table className = "table">
      <tbody>
        {
           _.chunk(this.state.imgs2, 3).map(chunk => (
                <tr> { chunk.map(img => 
                (<td>{this.renderImage(img, "150", "150")  } </td>)
                 ) } </tr>
             ))
        }
      </tbody>
    </table>
    )
```

Comment: oh sry how do I center the whole thing? basically as above so img4 and img5 are aligned center 
```
img1 img2 img3

  img4  img5
```

Comment: i suppose there is no semantics of using `table` so you could use ordinary divs and center them using bootstrap or flexbox css

Comment: thanks how wud you css it so when the view width becomes way too short for 3 images to fit (like from com to phone) u can change to 2 images then 1 image if it ever happened?

Comment: You can use flex wrap property or see the auto grid system of bootstrap

Comment: cud u show a sample code of it? im quite confused about it because rn u r forced to have 3 images

Comment: https://eth.af/jackdille this is what i want my images to look like